# Automatically open popup on layer add

Tags: javascript, leaflet

**I have a polyline that needs to have a popup automatically open when the user selects the polyline layer in the layers control menu.**

> This method did not work for me:

```
var polyline = L.geoJson(myData).bindPopup("<h1>Some Text goes here</h1>").openPopup();
```

**How can I do the auto popup?**

Here's my current setup:

```
var polyline = L.geoJson(myData).bindPopup("<h1>Some Text goes here</h1>");

var overlaysMenuCtrl = L.Control.extend({ ... blah blah... });

map.addControl(new overlaysMenuCtrl)());
```

I extend the control and add a custom function to check for layers that are toggled on/off by the user:

```
function toggleLayer(checked, layer){
    if(checked){
        map.addLayer(layer);
    } else {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
}

$(".check").change(function(){
    var layerClicked = $(this).attr("id");
//Turn layers on and off based on the ID of the radio checked
   switch(layerClicked){
    case "polyline": toggleLayer(this.checked, polyline);
    break;
    ...and other layers ...
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<label><input id="polyline" type="checkbox" class="check">Polyline layer</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is very probably a delay between the moment you request to add your layer to the map, and when that layer is actually on map / ready to open its popup.

You could simply add an event listener (use the [`"add"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layer-add) event) that will automatically open the popup whenever the layer is added to the map:

```js
layer.on("add", function (event) {
  event.target.openPopup();
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/101/ (use the Layers Control to add the layer to the map)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using a custom overlays menu that I need to use for this particular project for ease of styling, hence the reason for extending the control like shown in the code. On the other hand, I may just style the bindTooltip function since that methods works.

Comment: Whether you add the layer programmatically (through a custom control) or using the Layers Control should not affect this solution. Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/102/

Comment: Thanks, gyhbs. unfortunatley, still had issues with IE. So, I did some research and found I had to add this:                     L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(container);
that fixed my issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run `openPopup()` **after** the polyline has been added to the map.

Comment: I tried: case "polyline":toggleLayer(this.checked, polyline); polyline.openPopup(); and it works in Chrome, but abruptly closes in IE. I also get an error in console: 'must add layer to map before using getCenter()'